# Latest Google.Cloud.Translation.V2 no longer compatible with UWP app

Tags: google-translate, google-cloud-translate

I have been using Google.Cloud.Translation.V2 in a UWP app for a while. Its latest NuGet package is 3.1.0. Upgrading from 2.x to 3.x results in the following error:

> NU1202: Package Google.Cloud.Translation.V2 3.1.0 is not compatible
> with uap10.0.19041 (UAP,Version=v10.0.19041) / win10-x64-aot. Package
> Google.Cloud.Translation.V2 3.1.0 supports:
>
> - net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2)
> - netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

Does this mean the newer versions will no longer work with UWP apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean the newer versions will no longer work with UWP apps?

**TLDR;** UWP is not a supported platform

---

From this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/6587#issuecomment-855244851):

> We don't currently support UWP, and even if using grpc-dotnet makes it technical work, it's unlikely that we will prioritize UWP support over other work. So when we *have* moved over to grpc-dotnet by default, you may be in a situation where you can try to use the libraries and quite possibly be successful, but we would still not support it.

Also shown in this [comment](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/6578#issuecomment-858095365):

> To reiterate: **UWP is not a supported platform for these libraries**. You could potentially use the `Google.Apis.*` NuGet packages, which don't use gRPC, but again, UWP isn't a supported platform for those either.

---

*Final note* (from this [comment](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/6587#issuecomment-855764144)):

> You *may* find that the REST-based libraries for whichever APIs you're using (packages starting "Google.Apis") work, but again those aren't actually *supported* on UWP.